# VB.NET/ASP.NET Send Automated Gmail Outgoing Messages with OAuth

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gmail, google-oauth, gmail-api

My VB.NET/ASP.NET application sends automated emails to my users using the following code.  I received an email from Google that they will be discontinuing "less secure" applications and requiring OAuth.  All emails are sent *automatically* for upcoming appointment reminders and changes in appointments.  I can't have something that requires a manual login to an email account every time the application needs to send an email.

Here is my current code.  Can anyone guide me on how to modify this to work with credentials generated in the Google Developer Console for my Gmail email account?

Public Shared Sub SendEmailInBackground(Recipient As String, Subject As String, Message As String)

```
    Dim server As String = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("SmtpHostname")
    Dim username As String = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("SmtpUsername")
    Dim password As String = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("SmtpPassword")

    Dim email As New System.Net.Mail.MailMessage(username, Recipient)
    email.Subject = Subject
    email.Body = Message

    Dim client As New System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient(server, 587)
    client.Credentials = New System.Net.NetworkCredential(username, password)

    client.EnableSsl = True
    client.Send(email)
```

End Sub

Comment: [Using Gmail SMTP OAUTH](https://www.emailarchitect.net/easendmail/sdk/html/object_oauth.htm). I suggest you dismiss the [old SmtpClient class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.mail.smtpclient) (see the banner) there and pick a new one. See the Remarks section for a suggestion. [MimeKit](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MimeKit/) is also ok.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I had been in touch with the EASMail support people, and they explained that the code would require interactivity - logging in interactively with an email/password to receive a token each time the app wanted to send an email. My application sends automated emails all the time to remind people of upcoming appointments and appointment changes and need to remedy with a secure way to use GMail in compliance that runs like a service account.  Any suggestions on how to proceed?

Answer (score 0):

Going through the quickstart steps will allow you to have the oauth set-up [1]  and then use the authenticated service you got from there to make send email [2] requests. Documentation example using authenticated GmailService from quickstart:

```
using Google.Apis.Gmail.v1;
using Google.Apis.Gmail.v1.Data;

// ...

public class MyClass {

  // ...

  /// <summary>
  /// Send an email from the user's mailbox to its recipient.
  /// </summary>
  /// <param name="service">Gmail API service instance.</param>
  /// <param name="userId">User's email address. The special value "me"
  /// can be used to indicate the authenticated user.</param>
  /// <param name="email">Email to be sent.</param>
  public static Message SendMessage(GmailService service, String userId, Message email)
  {
      try
      {
          return service.Users.Messages.Send(email, userId).Execute();
      }
      catch (Exception e)
      {
          Console.WriteLine("An error occurred: " + e.Message);
      }

      return null;
  }

  // ...

}
```

[1] https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/dotnet

[2] https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/send